# How to configure keycloak in .net7 web api

Tags: c#, keycloak

I can't get a response from method. When i get access token with Postman, i use it to authorize in swagger. But when i try to get a response from method ('/') with response ''Hello world'',i see next error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

How i can fix this problem?

My Program.cs looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme() {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://localhost:8080/realms/vapestore-realm";
    jwtOptions.Audience = "vapestore-client";
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello world").RequireAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

And config of adapter is:

```
{
  "realm": "vapestore-realm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "vapestore-client",
  "public-client": true,
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

I try to change settings of swagger or code in builder.Services(...), but this problem is not fix.